# Converting date from DD-MON-YY to DD-MM-YYYY with NLS_DATE_FORMAT

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to store date type data from `Oracle FORMS` with format mask as like `DD-MM-YYYY` but every time it store as like `DD/MON/YY`.
I already alter session with `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, but result is as same as before.

Comment: _Please guide me._ First, [edit] your question and post what you tried. Are you trying to store a value in a DATE column in a database table? The date format has nothing to do with the value stored. It is used only for displaying the value. (Assuming the data type is DATE.)

Comment: I'm sending data to DB from `ORACLE FORMS`. I already give format mask to data file as `DD-MM-YYYY` and alter DB session as like as format mask. But after submit the forms then date stored with `DD/MON/YY` format.

Comment: _I'm sending data to DB from ORACLE FORMS_ I repeat: [edit] your question and post the code that sends data to DB from _Oracle Forms_

Comment: You must distinct between how the date is **stored** in the database and how it is **displayed** in your client application. In Oracle the `DATE` is **stored** as binary value with an internal format (which you should not care about) The `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` defines the **default display** format.  It is not clear what you are looking for. Note, some clients, e.g. TOAD display date format defined by internal application settings regardless of NLS_DATE_FORMAT settings.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle internal date format that is written in the table is something you can't change in any way, but, in the same time, it is irrelevant. If you are dealing with DATE type column then you should know that it containes both the date and the time. How, where and when you will show it or use it is on you.  Here is a sample of a few formats derived from that original Oracle DATE format...

```sql
WITH 
    t AS
        (
            Select SYSDATE "MY_DATE_COLUMN" From Dual
        )
Select
    MY_DATE_COLUMN "DATE_DEFAULT_FORMAT",
    To_Char(MY_DATE_COLUMN, 'mm-dd-yyyy') "DATE_1",
    To_Char(MY_DATE_COLUMN, 'yyyy/mm/dd') "DATE_2",
    To_Char(MY_DATE_COLUMN, 'dd.mm.yyyy') "DATE_3",
    To_Char(MY_DATE_COLUMN, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "DATE_4"
From t
```

| DATE_DEFAULT_FORMAT | DATE_1 | DATE_2 | DATE_3 | DATE_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22-OCT-22 | 10-22-2022 | 2022/10/22 | 22.10.2022 | 22.10.2022 10:59:44 |

You can find a lot more about the theme at https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-date/
Regards...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know if I use `TO_CHAR` then I can get any format what I want. But there have any `PARAMETER` or `FUNCTION` which can help me to store my data as per my choice like `DD-MM-YYYY` or `DD MONTH, YYYY` or `DD-MON-YYYY`.
Thank you.

Comment: You can do it only if the column in your table is of type VARCHAR2 (or similar). If the tsble column is of type DATE then it is not possible. DATE datatype has its own format managed by Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type consisting of 7-bytes (representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second). It **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

> every time it store as like `DD/MON/YY`.

As already mentioned, no, it does not store a date like that; the database stores dates as 7 bytes.

What you are seeing is that the client application, that you are using to connect to the database, is receiving the 7-byte binary date value and is choosing to convert it to something that is more easily comprehensible to you, the user, and is defaulting to converting the date to a string with the format `DD/MON/RR`.

What you should be doing is changing how the dates are displayed by the client application by either:

- Change the settings in the Toad (View > Toad Options > Data Grids > Data and set the Date Format option) and allow Toad to implicitly format the string; or
- Use `TO_CHAR` to explicitly format the date (`TO_CHAR(column_name, 'DD-MM-YYYY')`).

> I'm trying to store data as like `DD-MM-YYYY`.

If you want to store a date then **STORE** it as a date (which has no format) and format it when you **DISPLAY** it.

If you have a valid business case to store it with a format then you will need to store it as a string, rather than as a date, because you can format strings; however, this is generally considered bad practice and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Sadman, to add to what others have posted I suggest you do not write your applications with reliance on the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter but rather you screens and application should specify the expected DATE entry format and the code should use the TO_DATE function to store the data into the database.  All application SQL should use the TO_CHAR function to format date output for display.